# Getting error in react native . Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on react native project to develop expo app but i'm getting error that say native module cannot be null.
The following are the dependencies that i'm using for this project.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "randomatic": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.40.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.14",
    "react-qr-scanner": "^0.0.10"
  },
```

Comment: My hunch is that you have a dependency that is not supported by expo, https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9096

Might need to double check which one is not valid and find the supported library.

Comment: `Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException`

` what does this mean ?